# ASP.NET: Can't switch web application into DEBUG mode

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web application. For the application:

- Configuration set to "DEBUG;
- "Define DEBUG constant" checkbox is checked for "DEBUG" configuration;
- web.config file contains 'true' as value for 'debug' attribute of 'compilation' node.

Nevertheless to everything the following code:

```
#if ( _DEBUG )
    const bool DebugMode = true; 
#else
    const bool DebugMode = false;
#endif
string strSettings = string.Concat("(DebugMode: ", DebugMode, ")");
```

put "DebugMode: False" into result string. In the same time I can't connect to the application with VisualStudio in debug mode...

**Question:**

how can I get real value of debugging mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this C#? The constant is `DEBUG`, not `_DEBUG`.

Comment: the constant is defined in visual studio... yes, it defaults to DEBUG but nothing is stopping you from renaming it to whatever in the world you want!

Comment: @Pauli, this is true, but the question does not do this. Nor would I call renamed compiler directives the "real value".

Answer (score 1):

Do you compile the website as a Web Application?

Your `_DEBUG` constant for Compile Pre-Processor directives are set by Visual Studio and passed to the compiler like this

```
csc /define:_DEBUG
```

But when you access the website its normally not compiled by Visual Studio, but the asp_net compiler and it only looks at the debug-attribute of the compilation section. You can check the value of this attribute at runtime using

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

If you REALLY need Symbols defined in your webpages, you can pass /define arguments to the compiler by specifying it in web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true">
         <compilers>
            <compiler language="C#;Csharp" compilerOptions="d:_DEBUG"/>
         </compilers>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Pauli, thanks for your answer. AS I mentioned I have web application (not a web site). It means application is need to be compiled by VS before accessing (in contrast to web site). Actually, for me is not clear what is a purpose of " <compilation debug="true">" option for application. AFAIK, It makes sense for web site, not for application.

Comment: AFAIK, even when compiling a website application through VS it will invoke the aspnet_compiler.exe and the only way to control it is through the compilation-section of web.config. You can check this by looking at your taskmanager when compiling the website. Check to see id a process called aspnet_compiler.exe shows up. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(v=VS.100).aspx